# Which type of list is returned by JPA's getResultList()

Tags: java, list, jpa, persistence

Simple question: When you execute a JPQL query with JPA with the method "getResultList" a List is returned. If I am not mistaken, a list in java is an interface, and so there are different types of Lists: ArrayLists, LinkedLists, etc ...

My question is simple, which type of List is returned by the getResultList mentionned above, and as a plus, if would happen to know why, I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: Just after asking my question I had a flash, is it JPA's own implementation the interface list that is returned?

Comment: java.util.List and it returns a List<T>

Comment: What difference does it make? You can check using myList.getClass.getCannonicalName().

Comment: You could find out for yourself by logging the output of `getResultList().getClass()`

Comment: The specific implementation is the responsibility of the JPA provider. JPA just knows its a `List`.

Comment: So in other words, it respects the interface List and thats all we know? I will try to output using the reflection methods you guys gave me. I was just curious as to performance, I had to put parts of the results of getResultList in another List, and while thinking about which one was ideal (in my case LinkedList was the one) I wondered about which kind of list JPA uses. I'm curious to know if JPA uses something like an ArrayList (which is great for index access) or something more memory friendly. And since we can use .get(index) well, I'm guessing it's something similar to an arraylist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from JPA's `getResultList()` method is any class that implements the `List` interface.
The consumer (you) has no need to know the concrete class name,
just access the return value using the `List` interface.